# Drawing 2D multiple vectors from an ordered list in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, vector, draw

**tl;dr How do I draw connecting 2D Vectors from a list of Coordinates**

First time questioneer, so bare with me if I am not following proper etiquette :D

I study mechanical engineering and I have been trying to create a visual aide for the addition of rotating and oscillating forces within an engine. Every piston initially has its own vector, consisting of a length and an angle.

```
vectors = [[Force, Angle], [Force, Angle], [Force, Angle], ...]
```

These are converted to x,y components in EXCEL (will include this in python later)

**Individual vector components**

```
vectors = [[0.00, 1296.16],
           [-1013.38, -808.14],
           [421.22, -96.14], 
           [-374.92, 778.53],
           [-374.92, -778.53], 
           [0.00, 0.00],
           [337.79, -269.38]]
```

These vectors are then added 1 by 1 for a step-by-step resultant

**x_coords
Out[183]:**

```
[0.0, -1013.38, -592.16, -967.08, -1342.0, -1342.0, -1004.21]
```

**y_coords Out[182]:**

```
[1296.16, 488.02, 391.88, 1170.41, 391.88, 391.88, 122.5]
```

[WHAT I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtB9N.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdHPW.png)

EXCEL CONVERSION

[Converting the data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNjNl.png)

**drawing in tkinter/mpl is appreciated, but I will accept any help :)**
**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']         # These will be replaced with Engine Firing Order
vectors = [[0.00, 1296.16],
           [-1013.38, -808.14],
           [421.22, -96.14], 
           [-374.92, 778.53],
           [-374.92, -778.53], 
           [0.00, 0.00],
           [337.79, -269.38]]


vectors = pd.DataFrame(np.array(vectors),columns=('x1', 'y1'))

x_coords = []
y_coords = []

sum_x = 0
sum_y = 0

for x in vectors['x1']:
    sum_x += x
    x_coords.append(round(sum_x,2))

for y in vectors['y1']:
    sum_y += y
    y_coords.append(round(sum_y, 2))

coords = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_coords, y_coords)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x_coords[i], y_coords[i]))

plt.show()
```

PS. Any suggestions/comments/tips about the code are appreciated :)

Comment: Why does this question have the `tkinter` tag? Also look at [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

Comment: I'm working towards a way to visualise the vectors, drawing in tkinter seemed easiest but I've used mpl to visualise the scatterplot.